# Can't write to file /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness (ubuntu)

Tags: linux, sudo, brightness, su

I am trying to change the brightness by overwriting the value on this file:

```
sudo echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
-bash: /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness: Permission denied
```

It doesn't work even when using sudo. However if I switch to super-user with su, it works. Why is that?

Comment: This action is restricted  to sudo users only. I found an answer [in this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script#comment1285547_469040): `The reason that this is set at su permissions is that a virus could conceivably make your screen dim and go bright at incredible speed ultimately damaging your hardware display. In the 90's I encountered a virus that would adjust the screen refresh Hertz so rapidly that your monitor would fry.`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error happens because sudo elevates permissions for the command (`sudo echo 5`) but not the redirection to write the file (`> /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`). The actual bash shell needs permission to write, which is why it fails with sudo but works as root.

You can work around this by running the `tee` command as root to write to the file:

```
echo 5 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Note that this will also echo "5" to your terminal. This is a normal side effect of the `tee` command.

Comment: Credit goes to @duskwuff for the clever `tee` solution

Comment: I can't take credit for coming up with that -- it's a bit of UNIX folklore I picked up from who-knows-where.

Comment: not working for me with /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_sclk_od 
cannot change the value

Answer (score 23):

As written in the Arch wiki ([link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight)), by default, only `root` can change the brightness by this method. To allow users in the `video` group to change the brightness, a `udev` rule such as the following can be used (replace the `<vendor>` with your vendor id. E.g. `acpi_video0`, `intel_backlight`) :

```
% cat /etc/udev/rules.d/backlight.rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", KERNEL=="<vendor>", RUN+="/bin/chgrp video /sys/class/backlight/%k/brightness"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", KERNEL=="<vendor>", RUN+="/bin/chmod g+w /sys/class/backlight/%k/brightness"
```

Then you need to add your user to the `video` group.

```
usermod -aG video <user>
```

After that this should work:

```
echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/<vendor>/brightness
```

Comment: This method works for me, after replacing `acpi_video0` by `intel_backlight`.

Comment: Thx for your feedback. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I'm using debian 10, and the output of `groups` showed that my non-root account is already in `video`. Also, I had to reboot before this answer worked for me.

Comment: This is the better way to do that. It must the accepted answer

Comment: Should be an accepted answer. Now I can run a custom script to adjust backlight with non-root user

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't want 5 to be echoed this also works:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this problem on my VAIO VPCEG for quite a time. After doing everything mentioned in every forum I found something interesting:

After changing the boot parameter `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` and trying to manually change `/sys/class/backlight/[vendor - in my case intel_backlight]/brightness`, I realized that changing permission to this file from root to my user and restarting acpid service, this would allow me to use brightness keys flawlessly.

Comment: `"changing permission to this file from root to my user"` - this will get reset at next reboot.

Comment: @TheEagle why? how to make it persistent?

Answer (score 0):

the below solutions works fine for me..

i am posting it as answer so that others might get help:

change the permission:

`sudo chmod a+rw /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

now change brightness:

`echo 400 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

in your case it would be: `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://superuser.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Super User way of saying thank you.

Comment: In addition you didn't really answer the question, which was "Why is that?"

Comment: thanks a lot.. for the information and really sorry.. just because of me.. you wasted your important time for guiding me..i will make sure this doesn't happen again

Comment: It is not good practice to allow everyone to read and write a system config file like that.

Comment: I have some scenarios, where the screen starts functioning, yet the backlight value is still 0,

Comment: Also you have to redo this after every reboot

Answer (score 0):

The solution with `tee` is much better suited for scripting and such, but I found that simply editing the file with for example `vim` run using `sudo` works as well and is easier for me when I'm just doing it manually.